# Nested loops and modulus c++

Tags: c++, loops, nested-loops, modulus

I am learning C++ and I have a problem with my program. It should print out following if `n=11`:

```
*---------*
-*-------*-
--*-----*--
---*---*---
----*-*----
-----*-----
----*-*----
---*---*---
--*-----*--
-*-------*-
*---------*
```

This is my code, which works correctly with n=5, but not with greater numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int n;

    cout << "Enter size (n x n): " << endl;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if (i%n==j%n) cout << '*';
            else if (i%(n-i)==j%(n-j)) cout << '*';
            else cout << '-';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is being printed out if `n=11`:

```
*---------*
-*----*--*-
--*-----*--
---*---*---
----*------
-----*-----
-*----*--*-
---*---*---
--*-----*--
-*----*--*-
*---------*
```

I see that I have successfully wrote how to print out one of '*' diagnoles. But something isn't working with other one, which is going backwards.
Unfortunately, I am not being able to resolve this problem and need your advice. What am I doing wrong? How to debug such problems?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you have to solve this with the mod operator? This seems like a weird way of doing it...

Comment: I had a similar exercise that used mod operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is really simple to debug.

Take a look at the first erroneous `*`. It appears at the position with `i=1`, `j=6`. With `n=11`, your condition `i%(n-i)==j%(n-j)` becomes `1%(11-1) == 6%(11-6)` which is effectively true because the expression evaluates to `1` on both sides.

What is behind this expression? Why do you use this kind of `if` to determine whether the cell belongs to the second diagonal? Try to write down each pair `i, j` which should be printed on the second diagonal, and you should notice a more simple pattern.

P.S. In the expression `if (i%n==j%n)` you don't have to take operands modulo `n`, because both of them are less than `n`, so it is redundant and may be rewritten simply as `if (i == j)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You put me on the right path, I solved it!